# Bluetooth on windows 10, disable profiles

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

On Windows 10 when I turn on Bluetooth i have 5 different Bluetooth profiles enabled by default.

- A2DP
- AVRCP
- PAN
- Unknown Service
- there was also HFP but it disappeared when i disabled Bluetooth Audio Gateway Service and restarted

How do i disable this profiles?
I want to disable it because I'm about to start my own profiles programatically and not let windows 10 interfere.

Comment: Bluetooth profiles only come from paired devices. Delete the paired devices and the profiles will disappear.

Comment: There is no paired Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record:

I disabled this windows services :

- Connected Devices Platform Service
- Bluetooth Audio Gateway Service
- Avctp Service

Now all profiles are gone except PAN, To disable PAN i disabled Bluetooth Network Connection (in control panel).

Comment: This should be an edit to the question, not an answer, because you still have a question. Please read our Help section to learn how Superuser works.